# After Small Business Server 2011 VM has been migrated from VMWare to KVM, it stopped reacting to input devices

Tags: vmware, linux-kvm

I have to migrate a ESXi-based Small Business Server 2011 VM to KVM (from rather old ESXi to KVM provided by Ubuntu 18.04)

Disk conversion by itself worked normally. .vmdk volume has been converted to .qcow2, like this:

```
qemu-img convert -f vmdk source.vmdk target.qcow2
```

After that, the disk was added as an IDE drive and booted at first attempt without BSOD/whatever.

However, it doesn't respond to input devices (mouse or keyboard). Since I need to install its network interface driver, I can only use virt-manager GUI to access the VM.

I can normally shut down  VM via virt-manager GUI control, and it starts again, normally, but that's all.

What are possible additional/preliminary steps to make Windows VM understand KVM input devices?

Thanks.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator No. As I said, I need to install network interface driver first. And I need input devices for that.

Comment: yes of course. One option would be to install the NIC driver before converting the disk for KVM.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator An interesting idea. I'l look whether I can install VirtIO device driver into an existing Windows VM. I only should understand which files to copy.

Comment: I would hope you could perform the installation the same way you would once the VM were running on the target hypervisor. It's possible to install drivers even if the device they support isn't currently installed.